# What to do when a text is too long to fit into a text label component?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a Canvas app with a Gallery. In the Gallery I have a Text label field.

I have found out that sometimes my App puts into the Text label field a string that is too long; in other words – a string that is too long to be fully displayed in the given Text label. And I see that **the text is just truncated** in such situation.

Can I have the Text label (or a Text input, or some other component) to at least show to my end-users that the given text is truncated? Something like dots in the end of a displayed part (“Begin of the string…”); or vertical scroll bar in the control; or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approaches:

1. Set `AutoHeight` to `true` to allow the label to auto-grow its height to show all text. Set to false to truncate the text to the height assigned.
2. Set "Text" property of label control to show `...` using formula. for example:

```
If(Len("Long Text") > 45, Concatenate(Left("Long Text", 45), "..."), "Long Text")
```

You can change the value `45` as per the width of your label control and your requirements.